# MYSQL Query Error (Result Array)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this result

```
Furni Count: Array
```

My code is

```
$query2 = mysql_query(
                "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM items
                 WHERE base_item='" . $weekly2['furniture_id'] . "'"
           );

$OwnerCount = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
echo "<tr><td width=\"92%\" >Owner Count: $OwnerCount<form><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Owner Last Online\"></form></td></tr>";
```

Comment: EDIT:
I added these lines and I get the result: 6,6  

$string=implode(",",$OwnerCount);
echo $string;

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it, I added [0] and got the result 6 as I wanted, so my code is

$string=implode(",",$OwnerCount); echo $string[0];

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `echo`ing an array, try `print_r($Ownercount);` and you should see the array (and the keys).

Example:

```
echo $Ownercount[0];
```

Should return the first key in the array (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Echo $OwnerCount[0]; and I get nothing(Owner Count: )
Print_r($OwnerCount); and I get the result Owner Count: print_r()

Answer (score 0):

you can put an alias on the query, like this :

```
COUNT(DISTINCT id) as total
```

and then call

```
$Ownercount["total"];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING